# Determine the run-time of a pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, runtime, pseudocode

I have the following pseudo-code which I want to determine its run-time T(n).
Can someone please give me the steps I should follow ?
Here is the code:

```
i := 1;
while (i <= n)
   j := i;
   x := x+A[i];
   while (j > 0)
      y := x/(2*j);
      j = j /2; // Assume here that this returns the floor of the quotient
   i = 2 * i;
return y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's `O(log log N)` if my calculation is not wrong.

First, we omit the lines that does not affect the loop times, also assume array random visit as `O(1)`.

```
i := 1;
while (i <= n)
   j := i;
   while (j > 0)
      j = j / 2;
   i = 2 * i;
return y;
```

Then we assume that all the operations in one line are done in O(1), we add them up and get the result.

[image: Calculation]

Besides the math analysis, we can also use computational: we run the fragment for several times and see the time growth (I also omitted the operations that does not affect the loop times).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long i, j, n;
    double cost;
    clock_t start, finish;
    i = 1;
    n = 1000000000000;
    start = clock();
    while (i <= n) {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0) {
            j = j / 2;
        }
        i = 2 * i;
    }
    finish = clock();
    cout << (double)(finish - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}
```